# MongoDB insert and upsert not working properly - using meteor frame work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor framework version 1.2.1
I have a form which adds data to Mongo collection. However I find that the javascript code executes without errors (and all the debug console.log messages appear as i expect) but still the collection doesn't have the data which i just inserted. The issue is that this happens kind of randomly. So sometimes the insertion is working and at other times the insertion doesn't work. Similar issue with the upsert command. my html and js code is pasted below (Note i haven't removed autopublish and insecure packages). Unable to figure what the issue in my code is and need help in this matter

## JS Code

```
ProjectList = new Mongo.Collection("projectList");
ListItem    = new Mongo.Collection("listItem");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.create.events({
  'submit .add_chapter': function (event) {
    var addtoWhat;
    var chapName = event.target.chapName.value;
    if (event.target.addToWhat.value) {
      if (event.target.addToWhat.value.length > 0) {
        addtoWhat = event.target.addToWhat.value;
      } else {
      }
    } else {
    } 
    if (addtoWhat) {
      var addToWhatItem = ListItem.findOne({name:addtoWhat});
      var item = {
        name : chapName,
        list : [],
      }
      var id = ListItem.insert(item);
      if (id) {
        addToWhatItem.list.push(id);
        if (!ListItem.upsert({_id:addToWhatItem._id}, addToWhatItem))  {
          alert("Unable to upsert");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Unable to insert");
      }

    } else {
      var projList;
      if (!ProjectList.findOne({projectId:"123"})) {
        projList = {
          projectId : "123",
          list : [],
        };
        var topid = ProjectList.insert(projList);
        if (topid) {
          console.log ("Top Insert succesful with id " + topid);
        } else {
          console.log ("Error Top Insert unsuccesful with id ");
        }
      }
      projList = ProjectList.findOne({projectId:"123"});
      var item = {
        name : chapName,
        list : [],
      }
      var id = ListItem.insert(item);
      projList.list.push(id);
      if(!ProjectList.upsert({_id:projList._id}, projList)) {
        console.log("Upsert failed");
      } else {
        console.log("Upsert successful");
      }
    }
  }, 
  'submit .gen_tree' : function(event) {
     getElements();
  }

});

function getElements() {
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

## HTML Code

```
         <head>
           <title>test_hierarchy2</title>
         </head>

         <body>
           <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
           {{> create}}
         </body>

         <template name="create">
           <form class="add_chapter" method="post">
             <label>addToWhat</label>
             <input type="text" name="addToWhat">
             <label>chapName</label>
             <input type="text" name="chapName">
             <button type="submit">Add</button>
           </form>
           <form class="gen_tree" method="post">
              <button type="submit">generate</button>
           </form> 
         </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ProjectList.update({_id:projList._id}, projList, {upsert:true}, function(error,doc){
   if(error){
       console.log(error);
   }
   else{
       console.log(doc);
   }
})
```

Comment: This didn't help. However i expected some message to be printed on the console whether there is error or not, but didn't get any message.

Comment: One more thing. the callback has some print when the collection is updated properly.

Comment: So did it work ?? And what is that printed on the console ?